# The pin doesn't fit to pi zero w provide from Adafruit

Tags: pi-zero-w

I bought a starter package from Adafruit at [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3411) with three kinds of ping included (a female header, a male header, a right angle female header)

But as I take it to my teacher it said to connect it to pi zero w just plug it in it doesn't require welding but as we plug it in both three type of ping it'll shake which is NG for electronics so I was wondering what's the right way to connect pin to zero w or the pin is not the right type for pi zero w since I think that Adafruit is a fine company (an official partner) why the pin doesn't fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to solder the connectors that come with that kit to the Raspberry Pi. Nice kit, I've bought a few of those.

Comment: The blue "T" one?

Comment: There is an image it set up here https://www.adafruit.com/product/2028

Comment: Then when we solder the connector to zero w can it still fit into the case?

Comment: Yes, using the case provided with that kit you will be able to access the 40 pin connector.